# MySQL LIke statement with a twist on wildcard

Tags: mysql

I'm hoping someone can help me with a MySQL Query I'm trying to create.

Table: Customers
Columns: id, customer_firstname, customer_secondname, comments

Objective: Run a query that looks for a phrase, with some consideration given to variances.

For example, I want to find:

"Customer is located **in** London"
"Customer is located **near** London"
"Customer is located **towards** London"

But I do not want to find:

"Customer is located **in a city near** London"

I only want a single word 'wildcard' in the query.  Thus far, I have:

SELECT
cx.customer_firstname, cx.customer_secondname, cx.comments

FROM
custdatacx

WHERE
cx.comments like '%located % London%'

but this is giving me "Customer is located **in a city near** London" which I want to avoid.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How many words like, "in", "near", "towards" do you expect to have? If it's very few, then you could just use OR to get all cases.

Answer (score 3):

With MySQL You can use a `RLIKE` instead of `LIKE` which used regular expression and use an OR (`|`)

```
SELECT cx.customer_firstname, cx.customer_secondname, cx.comments
FROM custdatacx
WHERE cx.comments rlike 'located (in|towards|near) London'
```

Comment: `rike` should have been `rlike` in your example

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the chapter about regular expressions in the MySQL manual. Using regexes, you can do a much more sophisticated text search.

That said, I would seriously think about changing your philosophy. Save the city as a column, calculate the distance instead of using 'near', so you can change you criteria to look for data. 'Near' is quite imprecise and open to interpretation. Say, tomorrow you want to know who lives near Oxford... Will your comments still work?